# How to get the path of calling batch file in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, batch-file, path

Is there a way in delphi to determine in which folder the batch file is which called the .exe?

For example there are 2 folders and a batch file:

```
c:\application\program.exe
c:\files\data.dat
c:\batch.bat
```

And the code of the batch file is:

```
application\program.exe -open "files\data.dat"
```

Then in Delphi i just get "files\data.dat" as commandArgs[0]. Is there a way to determine from where the batch file called me, so that i can build the full path?

I know that i can write in the batch file:

```
application\program.exe -open "%~dp0files\data.dat"
```

In this case the batch file resolves the path and passes the full path to delphi, but thats not the question.

Comment: I don't understand this question. That `%~dp0` gives you the path from where the batch file was executed, so I'm quite confused what you're having trouble with. Could you elaborate a bit on what you actually want to pass to that `-open` parameter ?

Comment: The question is simply, can i know where the batch file lies which called me? the thing is, that i don't write the batch file. i want to provide the convenience to the user who writes the batch files, so that he does not have to know anything about cryptic batch commands, even if its simple in this case.

Comment: This makes no sense. `ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))`?

Comment: whats up guys? this makes perfect sense, you just don't seem to get it...

Comment: You shouldn't want to know. When the batch file gives you a relative path like `files\data.dat`, you should treat it as such and work from your app's folder: either the one you can find using `ParamStr(0)` as @user539484 suggested or from the current dir (just bear in mind that there are functions in the rtl/vcl that change the current dir). If the file isn't there, then treat that as an error. The batch file is responsible for providing a correct absolute or relative path. It is neigh impossible (as David mentions in his answer) to infer anything about or from where the batch file lives.

Comment: @thalm, this is a sign what **you** should spent more time formulating your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in delphi to determine in which folder the batch file is which called the .exe?

That depends. If you know that the batch file lives in the parent directory of the directory which contains the executable, then you can do this:

```
ExeDir := ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0));
ParentDir := ExtractFileDir(ExeDir);
```

On the other hand, if you have no special knowledge of where the batch file lives in relation to the executable, then there's no easy way to work out where it is. You can't expect to work it out from the working directory since that could, in general, be a directory other than the one containing the batch file.

So, if you do not control the batch file, then you can't expect to locate it easily and reliably. What's more, I'm not sure how you can be sure that there even is a batch file. The program could presumably be started by some other mechanism.

Comment: that's right... the effort to find the path of the batch file is in no relation to explaining the user how to write the batch file. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if the bat file is launching your exe then cmd.exe is the parent process and the batch file name is probably the cmdline of this cmd.exe. Start by veryfing with Process Explorer if this is true and if so get the parent process and kt's commandline programmatically

Comment: The cmd process will probably be terminated by the time the child process attempts to inspect its parent

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
application\program.exe -open "files\data.dat"
```

from the batch file, the process started to run `program.exe` should copy the current folder, so in this scenario you can use [`GetCurrentDir`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.GetCurrentDir) to read the full path of the batch file.

Comment: thanks, i will try whether this gives me the working dir of the batch file or the exe path...

Comment: @thalm It's the working directory of your Delphi process, whatever that happens to be.

Comment: I'm silently assuming the current path for the batch file will be the folder the batch file is in, since it won't work when started with a different folder as current path, because it is using a relative path to call the exe file.